# How can I select a text node using Rangy?

Tags: javascript, range, selection, rangy

I have a regular text node that I just inserted into the DOM.

I'd like to select it (same as if the user physically selected it with his mouse), either with Javascript or Rangy.

I have the following (and I think pretty ugly) code:

```
        // insert as regular text node
        var txt = document.createTextNode($mySpan.text());
        $myHeading.get(0).insertBefore(txt, $mySpan.get(0));

        // select again
        var sel = rangy.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges()

        var range = rangy.createRange();
        range.selectNode(txt);
```

I would love any help with this. I have no idea how to implement it, and goggling didn't work. The only way I can think of, is inserting 2 elements between the text, then select it, then remove the elements, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way.

Thanks, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless my eyes deceive me, the only thing missing from your code would be this line:

```
sel.setSingleRange(range);
```

Just add it to the end of what you currently have. (You could also remove `sel.removeAllRanges()`.)

Comment: What a moron..! I had that, and removed it. :-/

Thanks, Louis!

Comment: This works for other nodes (anchors in my case), not just text nodes.